# How update specific element of the array inside the a object in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, search, indexing

I need to update only one element of a list within an object in elasticsearch

Example:

```
{
    name: "anything",
    docs: [
    {
        id: "1",
        prop: "test",
        prop1: "test1"
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        prop: "other",
        prop1: "other1"
    }]
}
```

I need to update only the docs element with id 1

Comment: You can also add what you have tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove objects from array elastic search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26257884/remove-objects-from-array-elastic-search)